# python3がダウンロードできない

Tags: python, python3, windows

python3がダウンロードできません。

現在、左下のボタンを押すと、最近追加されたものとしてpyhton 3.6 Module Docs(64-bit)、IDLE(Python 3.6 64-bit)、Python 3.6 Manuals(64-bit)と表示されています。

これはダウンロードできていますでしょうか。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！python3がダウンロードできないとのことですが、どのような環境で、どのような操作をして、なぜダウンロードが出来なかったのか、などの情報を追記していただけますか？（[編集]ボタンから追記が可能です）

Comment: 左下のボタンを押すと、最近追加されたものとしてpyhton 3.6 Module Docs(64-bit)、IDLE(Python 3.6 64-bit)、Python 3.6 Manuals(64-bit)とあるのですが、これはダウンロードできていますでしょうか。

Comment: コメントからは恐らくWindowsなのかなと思いますが、Python自体は色々なOSで動作するものなので、利用している環境を明記しましょう。 / 「最近追加されたもの」はダウンロードではなくインストールしたアプリがスタートメニューでハイライトされる話なので、説明が食い違っているように思います。 / 試した手順を箇条書きにしてみるといいかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

## 現在の状況について

[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/55134/python3%e3%81%8c%e3%83%80%e3%82%a6%e3%83%b3%e3%83%ad%e3%83%bc%e3%83%89%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84#comment59093_55134)の内容から察するに、「Windowsを使っており、Python3を公式サイトなどからダウンロードし、インストールした。左下のWindowsロゴ（いわゆるスタート）をクリックしたところ、「最近追加したもの」の蘭にインストールしたPython関連のファイルが表示された」ということだと推測します。

このため、質問に対する回答は以下のようになります。

## Python3はダウンロードできているか

はい。